# jQuery/ajax is not updating divs on the page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to update a div with id=OCRID, which is a div on my page that contains some data. I used the code at the following URL first, however we switched to a jQuery approach. [<-Ugly ajax->](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp). Switched to this. Using alert, I saw that the message being returned on success was the correct message, but the `document.getElementById(OCRID).innerHTML=msg` doesn't change the value. I have some other javascript that does some similar things but not with data from the server. Please help?

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: url,
   data: "q="+OCRID+"&newstatus="+document.getElementById(OCRID).value,
   success: function(msg, OCRID){
     document.getElementById(OCRID).innerHTML=msg;
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you mentioned `OCRID` is an id of `div` and you've used

```
document.getElementById(OCRID).value // a div doesn't have a value attribute
```

which returns value of an `HTML` element but a `div` doesn't contain any value attribute and in the success callback you have used

```
success: function(msg, OCRID){
    document.getElementById(OCRID).innerHTML=msg; // innerHTML is right for a div
}
```

From the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) Documentation:

> **success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)**
>
> A function to be called if the
>   request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data
>   returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType
>   parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery
>   1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in
>   turn. This is an Ajax Event.

in this case you shouldn't use `OCRID` as the second parameter because `jQuery` uses 3 parameters in the `success` callback and these are basically `data, textStatus, jqXHR` and in this case `data` is your `msg`, `OCRID` in this case become `textStatus` and it is the response's status message and the third parameter is the `xhr` object. So it should be

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: "q="+OCRID+"&newstatus="+$('#'+OCRID).html(), // or text()
    success: function(msg){
        $('#'+OCRID).html(msg); // or text()
    }
});
```

Also remember that you `OCRID` looks like a variable and this should be available in the scope of your `ajax` call and if this is not a variable then it should be `$('#OCRID')` in both places as given below

```
$('#OCRID').html();
```

and in the success callback

```
$('#OCRID').html(msg);
```

Comment: Great explanation as to why my passing OCRID to the function was breaking it. Makes perfect sense and I should have read a manual on the function. Thanks for the tip :D

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
document.getElementById(OCRID).innerHTML=msg;
```

With:

```
document.getElementById("OCRID").innerHTML=msg; // notice the quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the jQuery version for the interface to the element? To me it looks like `OCRID` is a variable, right?

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: url,
   data: "q="+OCRID+"&newstatus=" + $('#' + OCRID).text(),
   success: function(msg, OCRID){
     $('#' + OCRID).html(msg);
   }
 });
```

Comment: A div doesn't have a value attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If your success callback has `OCRID` as a parameter(which is incorrect) it will be used instead of the one you used in your data parameter, so remove it.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: url,
   data: "q="+OCRID+"&newstatus="+document.getElementById(OCRID).innerHTML,
   success: function(msg){
     document.getElementById(OCRID).innerHTML=msg;
   }
 });
```

Comment: A div doesn't have a value attribute, you are using both (value and innerHTML) like OP and should consider to review your answer. Thanks!